# Why is SIGALRM not working second time?

Tags: c, system-calls

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<setjmp.h>
#include<signal.h>

jmp_buf  env;

void alarmHandler()
    {
        printf("\n in alarm Handle");

        longjmp(env,1);
    }



int main()
    {
        signal(SIGALRM,alarmHandler);

        alarm(2);

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("\nhello");
        sleep(1);

        if(setjmp(env))
            {

                printf("\n inside if");
                signal(SIGALRM,alarmHandler);
                alarm(2);
            }

    }


return 0;

    }
```

At start, actives monitor for signal then active alarm for 2 sec.(countdown).
Inside the `for` loop, every time, it keeps saving `setjmp(env)` as time ends last `setjmp(env)` will be called using `longjmp()`.
As `setjmp()` by default return 0  if called from `longjmp()`, whatever is second arg value is that value return.

Comment: Please indent your code; it is really hard to read when there's no indentation!

Comment: Note that `setjmp()` returns zero when first invoked, and returns non-zero when the return is from `longjmp()`.  You should end your `printf()` with a newline, too.  Otherwise, the output might not be seen.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler made change in  `printf()` still not working!

Comment: See also [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/).  You shouldn't officially use `printf()` — or `strlen()` and a number of other surprising omissions from the list of safe functions — inside a signal handler.

Answer (score 4):

The `longjmp` function is not considered a safe function to call in signal handlers.

By jumping like that you never actually leave the signal handler, the context of the process will still be the context of the signal handler. So how could another signal handler be called when we haven't even left the first one? That's why you should not do what you do.

Instead set a flag in the signal handler, and poll that flag in your loop instead. Then return from the signal handler normally, and let the process go on like normal.

Answer (score 2):

I got this code to work on Mac OS X 10.11.6 with GCC 6.1.0, but there are multiple things that could prevent it working elsewhere.  Amongst others, POSIX doesn't designate either `longjmp()` or `siglongjmp()` as safe for use in a signal handler (see POSIX [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)).  You shouldn't use [`printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891799#16891799) — or `strlen()` either — in a signal handler.

My default compilation options require the alarm handler to be static or declared before defined; the argument is necessary to avoid mismatches in the type of the pointer passed to `signal()`; the signal number needs to be used (but I could have use `longjmp(env, signum)` to do that).

However, you can often get away with abusing the rules.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

jmp_buf env;

static
void alarmHandler(int signum)
{
    printf("\nin alarm Handle (%d)\n", signum);
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);

    alarm(2);

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("\nhello");
        sleep(1);

        if (setjmp(env))
        {
            printf("\ninside if\n");
            signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
            alarm(2);
        }
    }
    printf("Exiting\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
hello
hello
in alarm Handle (14)

inside if

hello
hello
in alarm Handle (14)

inside if

hello
hello
in alarm Handle (14)

inside if

hello
hello
in alarm Handle (14)
```

I got bored and interrupted it at that point.

I'm not sure if the addition of the newlines after the `printf()` statements is sufficient to make it work.